# fine grained ACLs in pulumi cloud

Tags: pulumi

It seems that by default a lambda function created by Pulumi has an `AWSLambdaFullAccess` permissions. This type of access is too wide and I'd like to replace it with fine-grained ACLs.

For instance, assuming I am creating a `cloud.Table` in my index.js file, I would like to specify that the lambda endpoint I am creating (in the same file) only has read access to that specific table.

Is there a way to do it without coding the IAM policy myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@pulumi/cloud` library currently runs all compute (lambdas and containerized services) with a single uniform set of IAM policies on AWS.

You can set the policies to use by running:

```
pulumi config set cloud-aws:computeIAMRolePolicyARNs "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaFullAccess,arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceFullAccess"
```

The values above are the defaults.  See https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-cloud/blob/master/aws/config/index.ts#L52-L56.

There are plans to support more fine-grained control over permissions and computing permissions directly from resources being used in `@pulumi/cloud` - see e.g. https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-cloud/issues/145 and https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-cloud/issues/168.

Lower level libraries (like `@pulumi/aws` and `@pulumi/aws-serverless`) provide complete control over the Role and/or Policies applied to `Function` objects.